# How does stack deal with content scrapers

Tags: discussion

[This](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28144/how-can-i-block-abusive-bots-from-accessing-my-heroku-app/28156#28156) is a pretty good question on dealing with content scrapers that hasn't had much attention.

It would be interesting to see what the higher level stack admins think about dealing with these people as there are so many sites that scrape stack sites.

Comment: (Not really an *answer* but:) Have a look at Jeff's "[Trouble in the House of Google](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/01/trouble-in-the-house-of-google.html)" post from last January for one data point.

Comment: @Su'good link, and an interesting read, wish for a bit more technical information though.

Comment: I think the answer in the article is this: 1. They aren't necessarily doing anything wrong as the content is licensed cc-by-sa. 2. Google will penalise them anyway, and google is the main source of traffic. That's why the article doesn't say how to stop them.

Comment: @paulmorriss indeed, but Jeff Atwood does refer to work they did on webmasters to counteract the problems they were facing while waiting for Google to spike the content farms - I can guess what they did but would like a little more.

Comment: Is this meta really the right place for this question? It feels to me like it should be either on the main webmasters.SE site (as an SEO question that just happens to reference SE) or on MSO (as a question about the whole SE network, not just this site).